# Conversion from Swit2.3 to Swift3 cause "Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-lambda, swift2

**Here is the code I want to convert from Swift2.3 to Swift3:**

```
AWSCloudLogic.defaultCloudLogic().invokeFunction(functionName,
                                                         withParameters: parameters, completionBlock: {(result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                                            if let result = result {
                                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                                                    print("CloudLogicViewController: Result: \(result)")
                                                                    //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                                                                    //self.resultTextView.text = prettyPrintJson(result)
                                                                })
                                                            }
                                                            var errorMessage: String
                                                            if let error = error {
                                                                if let cloudUserInfo = error.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject],
                                                                    cloudMessage = cloudUserInfo["errorMessage"] as? String {
                                                                    errorMessage = "Error: \(cloudMessage)"
                                                                    print(errorMessage)
                                                                } else {
                                                                    errorMessage = "Error occurred in invoking the Lambda Function. No error message found."
                                                                    print(errorMessage)
                                                                }
                                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                                                    print("Error occurred in invoking Lambda Function: \(error)")
                                                                    //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                                                                    //self.resultTextView.text = errorMessage
                                                                    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: "Title bar for error alert."), message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                                                    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Dismiss", comment: "Button on alert dialog."), style: .Default, handler: nil))
                                                                    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                                })
                                                            }
        })
```

Definition of Swift2.3:

```
/**
     Invokes the specified AWS Lambda function and passes the results and possible error back to the application asynchronously.

     @param name AWS Lambda function name, e.g., hello-world
     @param parameters The object from which to generate JSON request data. Can be `nil`.
     @param completionBlock handler for results from the function
     */
    public func invokeFunction(name: String, withParameters parameters: AnyObject?, completionBlock: (AnyObject, NSError) -> Void)
```

**And here is Swift3 version:**

```
    AWSCloudLogic.defaultCloudLogic().invokeFunction(functionName, withParameters: parameters) { (result : Any?, error: Error?) in


        if let result = result{
            print(result)

        }
        if let error = error{
            print(error)
            print("error")

        }else{

            print("No error but issue")
        }

    }
```

Definition of Swift3:

```
/**
 Invokes the specified AWS Lambda function and passes the results and possible error back to the application asynchronously.

 @param name AWS Lambda function name, e.g., hello-world
 @param parameters The object from which to generate JSON request data. Can be `nil`.
 @param completionBlock handler for results from the function
 */
open func invokeFunction(_ name: String, withParameters parameters: Any?, completionBlock: @escaping (Any, Error) -> Swift.Void)
```

**More detail:**

When I run this code on Swift 2.3 it works fine but when I run it in Swift 3 when it get to this line

```
AWSCloudLogic.defaultCloudLogic().invokeFunction(functionName, withParameters: parameters) { (result : Any?, error: Error?) in
```

It gets current error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

There is no other description!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 support has just been released, please download the MobileHub sample app again. Checking that it was generated with v0.10 template shown in any file's comments at the top.
https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home