# Does Xcode support AWSLambda for Swift3?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, aws-lambda, swift2

I have migrated my code to Swift 3 and all parts of my code is working except AWSLambda.

When it gets to this line

```
let cloudLogic = AWSCloudLogin.defaultCloudLogic()
```

It is crashing with this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Is this something happened because Lambda is not supported by Swift3? What could be the reasons for this error and how can I avoid it?!

Comment: Can you please give more details on the exception you're getting?

Comment: I can't see any more details. In Swift2.3 it used to worked with no problem. It is a singleton class and it must work properly. but once I updated to Swift3  in started to crash. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679850/conversion-from-swit2-3-to-swift3-cause-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of